# Hibernate, select where foreign key is null

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have entity as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LORRY")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Lorry.findSuitableLorries",
                    query = "SELECT l from Lorry l " +
                            "WHERE l.order IS NULL")
})
public class Lorry {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", length = 7)
    @Pattern(regexp="[a-zA-Z]{2}\\d{5}")
    @Size(min = 7, max = 7)
    private String regNum;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "lorry")
    private Order order;
}
```

Now I need to select all rows where order id is null in the LORRY table, but it doesn't seem to work as I get empty list every time. How can I check if foreign key is null using JPQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either `SELECT l from Lorry l WHERE l.order.id IS NULL` or `SELECT l from Lorry l left join l.order o WHERE o IS NULL`